# derivative of inverse of matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

I need the derivative of the following

$$ \Biggl\| \frac{\mathbf{1}^{T}(M - M_0) }{\mathbf{1}^{T}M}\Biggr\|_2^2 $$

w.r.t. the matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{B \times N}$ where $\mathbf{1}^{B \times 1}$ is a column vector of ones and $M_0$ is a **constant** of the same dimension as $M$.

Comment: Is this supposed to be the ratio of the norms of two vectors, or is there elementwise division going on inside of a single norm?

Comment: @greg the latter: element-wise division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, define the ${\tt1}\in{\mathbb R}^B$ all-ones vector
and the following ${\mathbb R}^N$ vectors
$$\eqalign{
a &= M^T{\tt1},\quad b = M_0^T{\tt1},\quad 
c = \frac{a-b}{a}= ({\tt1}-b\oslash a) \\
w &= 2\,c\odot b\oslash a\oslash a \\
}$$
and the associated diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= {\rm Diag}(a),\quad B= {\rm Diag}(b),\quad C= {\rm Diag}(c)= (I-BA^{-1}) \\
W &= 2BCA^{-2}\\
dC &= -B\,dA^{-1}= BA^{-2}dA \\
}$$

Then the function of interest can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|c\|^2 \\&= C:C \\
d\phi
 &= 2C:dC \\
 &= 2C:BA^{-2}dA \\
 &= W:dA \\
 &= w:da \\
 &= w : dM^T{\tt1} \\
 &= {\tt1}w^T : dM \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial M} &= {\tt1}w^T \\ \\
}$$
In the above, the symbol $(\odot)$ denotes elementwise multiplication,
$(\oslash)$ denotes elementwise division,
and $(:)$ represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Note that the $\{A,B,C,W\}$ matrices are diagonal and therefore they commute with each other, while the $M$ matrix is rectangular and does not commute with anything.

Comment: thank you very much for this. one Q I had re: numerical implementation of `w` --> since `a` is a vector that can have 0 entries, then, `w` won't be defined at these locations due to the inverse .... does it make sense to replace the 0's in `w` with a smaller number like 1e-6 or perhaps something else? thank you.

Comment: The given cost function $\phi=\left(\frac{a-b}{a}\right)$  implicitly assumes that $a\ne 0$. 
You've now discovered that this assumption is false. Therefore you need to construct 
a **NEW** cost function  which is well-defined at $a=0$ and calculate its gradient. 
Making _ad hoc_ tweaks to an invalid gradient is never going to work.

Comment: thank you for your help. one final Q: can you pls tell me what the derivative would be if the fcn was instead defined using the fourth norm, i.e., $\phi = \| \frac{a-b}{a} \|_4^4$? should i post this as another Q? thank you.

Comment: i posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730545/derivative-of-4-norm-of-matrix-vector-product