# derivative of 4-norm of matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I need the derivative of the following

$$ \Biggl\| \frac{\mathbf{1}^{T}(M - M_0) }{\mathbf{1}^{T}M}\Biggr\|_4^4 $$

w.r.t. the matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{B \times N}$ where $\mathbf{1}^{B \times 1}$ is a column vector of ones and $M_0$ is a **constant** of the same dimension as $M$. The case of $\| . \|_2$ was answered here [derivative of inverse of matrix-vector product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721287/derivative-of-inverse-of-matrix-vector-product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, define the ${\tt1}\in{\mathbb R}^B$ all-ones vector
and the following ${\mathbb R}^N$ vectors
$$\eqalign{
a &= M^T{\tt1},\quad b = M_0^T{\tt1},\quad 
c = \frac{a-b}{a}= ({\tt1}-b\oslash a) \\
w &= 4\,c\odot c\odot c\odot b\oslash a\oslash a \\
}$$
and the associated diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= {\rm Diag}(a),\quad B= {\rm Diag}(b),\quad C= {\rm Diag}(c)= (I-BA^{-1}) \\
W &= 4BA^{-2}C^3 \\
dC &= -B\,dA^{-1}= BA^{-2}dA \\
}$$

Then the function of interest can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= \|C\|_4^4 \\&=  I:C^4 \\
d\psi
 &= I:4C^3dC \\
 &= 4C^3:BA^{-2}dA \\
 &= W:dA \\
 &= w:da \\
 &= w : dM^T{\tt1} \\
 &= {\tt1}w^T : dM \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial M} &= {\tt1}w^T \\ \\
}$$
In the above, the symbol $(\odot)$ denotes elementwise multiplication,
$(\oslash)$ denotes elementwise division,
and $(:)$ represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Note that the $\{A,B,C,W\}$ matrices are diagonal and therefore they commute with each other, while the $M$ matrix is rectangular and does not commute with anything.